# Apply filter to t-foreach

Tags: odoo-11

Is there any t-filter tag capability in odoo 11 qweb template?

sample :

```
<tr t-foreach="o.line_ids" t-as="line_ids" t-filter="line_ids.name == 'car'">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'filtered' for filtering the records. So, you can do it like this:

```
<tr t-foreach="o.line_ids.filtered(lambda x: x.name == 'car')" t-as="line_ids">
```

According to the example from Odoo ORM API documentation:

```
records.filtered(lambda r: r.company_id == user.company_id)
```

filtered()

```
returns a recordset containing only records satisfying the provided predicate function. The predicate can also be a string to filter by a field being true or false:
```

This can also be applied in Qweb reports.
You can read more about this here - https://www.odoo.com/documentation/online/reference/orm.html